# Devise handle sign-out redirect in ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, devise

I have a Backbone.js client with Rails/Devise server.

I want to implement sign-out process with redirect.

here is my client-side code

```
$.ajax
  url: "/sign_out"
  xhrFields:
    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
  type: "DELETE"
  complete: xCompleteFunction = (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) ->
    #handle here?
```

The request is handled by the proper controller's method. Then I have

```
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    root_path
  end
```

Here is the log

```
[2012/12/11 15:44:07] (INFO) 76430 Started DELETE "/sign_out"
[2012/12/11 15:44:07] (INFO) 76430 Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as */*
....
[2012/12/11 15:44:07] (INFO) 76430 Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
```

Hoverer, the redirect is handled by the Rails controller, and in fact the redirect used the same verb "DELETE".

```
[2012/12/11 15:44:13] (INFO) 76430 Started DELETE "/" 
[2012/12/11 15:44:13] (INFO) 76430 Processing by HomeController#index as */*
```

Is that possible to handle the redirect on the client, and prevent Rails controller catching it? I was expecting that devise will return 301/302 to the client as a result of the ajax call.

Answer (score 6):

I've actually just hit this same problem as well.  It's possible to override the `Devise::SessionsController`, which was how I solved it.

Within the `Devise::SessionsController`, there's a [method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/868d3d82a014509167ccd7dd3e794171011bffe1/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L73) `#respond_to_on_destroy` which actually makes the redirect.  By overriding this, it just 200's.

```ruby
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  private

  # We sign out using Ajax calls so we override this method to render plain
  # text instead of redirecting unnecessarily
  def respond_to_on_destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.all { head :no_content }
      format.any(*navigational_formats) { render plain: "Signed out" }
    end
  end
end
```

There is a clear problem with this in that overriding a private method like this isn't great (the implementation that uses it may change without us realising), but I couldn't find any other way to do this nicely.  It would be great if Devise let you render instead of redirect in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to this problem too. I'm not exactly sure about handling the second redirect devise makes after the first DELETE request sent for logging out the user. But [here](http://rubythings.blogspot.com/2011/10/ajax-redirects-with-devise.html) I found that adding an ajax initialization code that catches a 401 (unauthorized) response solves the problem.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  statusCode: {
    401: function(){
      // Redirect the to the login page.
      location.href = "/admin/auth/sign_in";
    }
  }
});
```

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because by default your Ajax calls follows 302 ('Moved Temporarily') not as an error status but as to be retried for a second request if the location header is present.

Either change the status and redirect to the location header in your js code success callback, or return a nil location and handle the redirection on the client side.

If you want to differentiate a login by json and html then simply add conditionals on self.request.format.symbol in your controller code.